# 'Launch terminal' launches terminator instead of terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, terminator

I recently installed terminator in Ubuntu 14.04 TLS but when using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt +T it launches the terminator instead of the terminal. I'd like to regress back to having the shortcut launching the terminal but not sure how. Note that on the keyboard/Shortcuts/Launchers, the shortcut seems to be correctly mapped to 'Launch terminal'.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator $(which gnome-terminal.wrapper)`

The system has `x-terminal-emulator` , which is symlinked to a particular program. When you've installed terminator , that symlink has been somehow changed to terminator. The command above will restore that to gnome terminal.

Comment: Thanks both! followed the possible duplicate and it did the trick.  The 'sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator $(which gnome-terminal)' command returned the error : alternative /usr/bin/gnome-terminal for x-terminal-emulator not registered; not setting

Comment: Oh, I see. It should be `gnome-terminal.wrapper`. I'll correct it